# cannot access external hard drive from a previous computer

Tags: windows-8, windows-vista, external-hard-drive

using a new computer with windows 8 how can I access an external drive that was used as a backup for my previous computer that died. that computer had windows vista

Comment: What type of external disk was this specifically?

Comment: Some external drives have a password protect utility that runs when the disk is plugged in. It gets installed from the disk when you first use it. After that, the installer is of course only available after you supply the password. You may be able to download and install it from the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

I bought an Asus VivoBook Win8 "ultrabook" recently, but my older Acer Core i7 desktop is still the server on my WLAN, so I had access to my external drive on the Acer as soon as my VivoBook was registered on my WLAN. Do you still have your previous computer?